# Can I forward certain numbers directly to google voicemail

Tags: google-voice

i have a specific line that I want to always forward to voicemail on my google voice account. I came across the following link https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/voice/HELA3jdsezY/eSbOrYcYnjcJ , from 2012 which contains:

```
To set custom settings for a specific contact:
1 Click Contacts on the left side of the page.
2 Search for the contact you want to customize, and select the checkbox next to the name.
3 Click the Edit Google Voice Settings link.
4 Under 'When this contact calls you:' select the phones to ring by clicking the Edit link (NOTE: One of the options is "SEND TO VOICEMAIL").
5 Click Save.
```

However the GUI has changed . Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

while I could not figure out how to do it in the new GUI, you can switch to the Legacy Google Voice and do it.

Log into Google Voice and on the left hand nav there is a button that says "Legacy Google Voice" 
[image: Google Voice]

Then when the old version launches, click on the contact name you would like to forward to voicemail, in this case I used Test Contact:
[image: Click on Contact]

Then click edit:
[image: Edit Contact]

Then you can forward to voicemail

Comment: I havn't tried yet, but wanted to make sure you get the points. Thanks for taking the time to answer.